# sphinx 0.9.9 runs slower than 0.9.8

Tags: sphinxsearch

After upgrade of sphinx from 0.9.8 to 0.9.9 we ran into serious problems with performance. Searchd works on EC2 large instance.

Queries started to work much slower and i often could see Z (zombie) searchd processes in top.

I expect this may be related to full-scan queries.

Did anyone experience anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

We just tried to upgrade from 0.9.8.1 to 0.9.9 and we also experienced slower responses...
We went back to 0.9.8.1 until 1.0.

Comment: I was not able to find cause of it and had to keep 0.9.8 until now. I doubt 1.0 helps, but know knows...